# Celery: run tasks created by another app

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have several applications that communicate using RabbitMQ. I need to process messages from the queue in Python application, these messages are created and added to the queue by different application. Is there a way to configure Celery to process tasks that were not created in Python? Or is there some way to achieve this without using Celery?

Comment: Do you mean i) Tasks have been submitted to RabbitMQ in a format other than the one Celery uses, and you want Celery to use that format or ii) You are willing/able to modify the other applications to use Celery's format and want some guidance on how to do so?

Comment: I would want to do 1) but I don't know how, so for now I went with 2)

Comment: I assume you're using the webhooks - which language(s) are you working in?

Comment: Ruby + Python. I want to submit a message to RabbitMQ from Ruby and have it processed in Python